# Secure Elastic connection using transport client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-x-pack, xpack, transport-security

Need to connect to a secure elastic search which has https authentication using Transport client in java code. I have userId and password to connect secure elastic. I am using elasticsearch 7.10.0.

```
try {
            Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", clusterName)
                    .put("xpack.security.user", "elastic:elastic")      
                    .put("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled", "true")
                    .put("xpack.ssl.key", "/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.keystore")
                    .put("xpack.ssl.certificate", "/etc/elasticsearch/elastic-certificates.p12")
                    .put("xpack.ssl.certificate_authorities", "/etc/elasticsearch/elastic-stack-ca.p12")
                    .put("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled", "true")
                    .build();
            ESclient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);

            //changes for add multiple IP address
            String[] hosts = elasticHost.split(",");
            for (String host : hosts) {
                ESclient.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host.trim()), elasticPort));
            }
            System.out.println(ESclient.settings());
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception :" + ex);
            //logger.error("Exception : " + ex);
            throw ex;
        }
```

But its showing Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
```

Please let me know,what i am missing in above code.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason for using the [TCP transport client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html) which is deprecated instead of the [REST one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html)?

Comment: @val: can you provide example code to create secure elastic connection?

Comment: The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_encrypted_communication.html) explains how to do it for the Java REST client

Comment: @val : i have used transport client.but its showing "None of the configured nodes are available:".

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @val : keyStorePass.toCharArray() gives error?

Comment: @val: what is keyStorePass ?

Comment: The password to your keystore where the certificate is stored.

Comment: @val : RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder); its showing error:Not supported yet.:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException? let me know the solution.

Comment: Which version of ES and the REST client are you running?

Comment: Also you should comment my answer instead of your question ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225725/discussion-between-atul-thakre-and-val).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the TCP transport client anymore since it's been [deprecated in 7.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html). Instead you should use the [REST client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html) which communicates with your cluster over HTTP.

If you need to communicate over [HTTPS with your cluster](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_encrypted_communication.html), here is how to do it with the REST client:

```
// 1. create an SSL context to trust the CA that signed the ES server certificate
String keyStorePass = "keystorePassword";
Path trustStorePath = Paths.get("/etc/elasticsearch/elastic-stack-ca.p12");
KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(trustStorePath)) {
    truststore.load(is, keyStorePass.toCharArray());
}
SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(truststore, null);
final SSLContext sslContext = sslBuilder.build();

// 2. Basic authentication
final CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", "password"));

// 3. Changes for add multiple IP address
String[] hosts = elasticHost.split(",");
HttpHost[] httpHosts = Arrays.stream(hosts)
     .map(host -> new HttpHost(host.trim(), elasticPort, "https"))
     .collect(Collectors.toList())
     .toArray(new HttpHost[hosts.length]);

// 4. Build the low-level client
RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(httpHosts)
    .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
        @Override
        public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(
                HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {

            // set Basic credentials
            httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
            // set SSL context
            return httpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(sslContext);
        }
    });

// 5. Build the high-level client
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
```

If you need to migrate your Java code to use the new RETS client, the official documentation provides a [step-by-step guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.0/java-rest-high-level-migration.html) on what needs to be done.

Comment: I m using ES 7.10.0.

Comment: what is KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12") ?

Comment: That line is just to create a PKCS#12 keystore in which you will store the certificate to verify the server certificate.

Comment: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException ?

Comment: Can you update your question with the full stack trace you get please?

Comment: see my detail question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234013/error-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failurejavax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexcept

Comment: Still I don't see the detailed stack trace for SSLHandshakeException

Comment: See now i have update detail error in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234013/error-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failurejavax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexcept

Comment: I don't get why you have two questions for the same issue, the other one is at risk of being closed

Comment: Can you add `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` to the java command line of your client so we can get more insights?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225773/discussion-between-atul-thakre-and-val).

Answer (score 0):

Use x-pack-transport jar and PreBuiltXPackTransportClient constructor

```
Use x-pack-transport jar and PreBuiltXPackTransportClient constructor

            Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
                .put("xpack.security.user", "elastic:elastic")
                .build();
        TransportClient transportClient = new PreBuiltXPackTransportClient(settings);
        transportClient = transportClient.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300)));
```